# Why getParentsIdsByChild($productId); is returning empty for Child product?

Tags: magento2, module, uicomponent, magento2.2.4

I'm trying to get parent products id for child products but i'm getting empty result.

```
<?php


namespace CustomColumn\Addproductcolumn\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class ParentProductId extends Column
{
    protected $configurable;
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->_configurable = $configurable;
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {

        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {

            if($items['type_id'] == 'simple'){

                $productId = $items['entity_id'];
                $getParent = $this->_configurable->getParentIdsByChild($productId);

                if($getParent){
                    $items['parentid_col'] = $getParent[0];
                }else{
                    $items['parentid_col'] = "nothing found";
                }
            }
        }
    }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

**For Configurable Product**

> \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable;

```
$this->_configurable->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
```

**For Bundle Product**

> \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection $bundleSelection;

```
$this->bundleSelection->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
```

Also please make sure that you are getting correct simple product ID which is assigned to Configurable product.

Comment: Thanks, it's working for Configurable product, do you know how to get the bundle products?

Comment: Please check my updated answer for Bundle product as well.

Comment: I tried your guide for bundle product but it still return array empty. Anyone know the way to get bundle parent?

Comment: Which Magento version you are using. I would suggest to check that method from vendor folder and check product ID again.